# Level of control in browser add-on code: How low can I go?

Tags: javascript, perl, browser-addons

Never having written a browser add-on, it's difficult for me to 
phrase this question concisely (and search for existing work). 
When viewing  a news media site, when I click on the link to a 
news story, I would like to see only the text of the news article 
and prevent the browser from accessing *any* other URL in the 
story's source page, including pictures, videos and ads. I can 
do this in a terminal window with a Perl script: issue a get 
on the URL, find the story by analyzing the HTML, extract and 
print it -- or, as a CGI script, to a browser window. The 
functionally equivalent browser add-on would say, in effect, 
don't grab that URL I just clicked on, let *me* get it, let me 
parse the page that's returned, and let me build my display of 
its contents with my own priorities. Does the browser add-on 
model provide for this level of control? If so, where's a good 
primer for a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes.

If you are interested in making a Firefox/Chrome add-on you would be using JavaScript, which is a very powerful language. Anything you could do in JavaScript on the web page, plus much more when using browser-specific extension APIs, is possible in an add-on. If you aren't already familiar with JavaScript, my personal recommendation for learning is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). One approach for what you want to do would be to find anchor tags that link to articles, then add click event listeners to them that would start the routine you want (likely download the HTML using XMLHttpRequest or the 'fetch' API) and prevent the default behavior of following the link.